# Why does the second argument in the laravel method View::get() accept different value types?

Tags: laravel

I am going through the Laravel Bootcamp and found this code section:

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {

    return view('dashboard');

})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

 

Route::get('/chirps', [ChirpController::class, 'index'])

    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])

    ->name('chirps');
```

why does the get method seemingly take two different arugment types? `function () { return view('dashboard'); }}` is a callback function and `[ChirpController::class, 'index']` seems like an array but I am not sure what it does.

I come from a react/javascript background so maybe I am using the wrong mental model here. let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument is for setting a callback, but in laravel you can refer to those in different ways.

The most direct is setting the function directly but `[ChirpController::class, 'index']` is a callback as well. It refers to the `index` method inside the `ChirpController class`.

You'll see that in other places they even use strings like `App\Http\Controllers\ChirpController@index` as well.

Comment: callback vs callable